# Unable to install pythonnet

Tags: python, clr, python.net

I'm trying to install pythonnet in order to use clr module. But it doesn't work ...

Here is my command "Conda install -c pythonnet pythonnet"

and here as the results :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoXw4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBukR.png)

I tried several time to reinstall but i still have the same problem ...

Thank you and have a nice day !

Comment: what is your OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `conda install` does not work, try `pip install pythonnet`. Better, `python -m pip install pythonnet`. It is ok to use pip within conda. use conda as your first choice whenever you can. pip is the 2nd choice.

Note that pythonnet as of today still only support up to 3.7, according to https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/, although 3.8.1 according to https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet